# Use result from one query inside a query and join results

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that are structured with the following columns:

#### **Table `vehicles`**:

```
| id (PK) | model (FK) | state | plates | owner | registered | active |
|---------|------------|-------|--------|-------|------------|--------|
|    1    |     4      |  0,0  | D0491C |   4   |     1      |    1   |
|    2    |     1      |  1,0  | C8S0A1 |   5   |     1      |    0   |
|    3    |     2      |  0,0  | V8S0CA |   4   |     1      |    1   |
```

#### **Table `vehicle_database`**:

```
| id (PK) | year | brand |   model   |
|---------|------|-------|-----------|
|    1    | 2011 | Dodge | Charger   |
|    2    | 2009 | Ford  | Focus     |
|    3    | 2015 | Audi  | A6        |
|    4    | 2019 | BMW   | E60       |
```

`vehicles.model` is a foreign key to `vehicle_database.id`, and I would like to SELECT all results from the vehicles table by `owner`, and where the `registered` and `active` state are both 1. I also want to display the `vehicles.model`, however using the actual model name from the `vehicle_database`, some sort of concatenation on the year, brand and model columns.

For example, using the following search conditions:

> `owner = 4`
> `registered = 1`
> `active = 1`

I would like the result:

```
| id (PK) |    modelName    | state | plates | owner | registered | active |
|---------|-----------------|-------|--------|-------|------------|--------|
|    1    |   2019 BMW E60  |  0,0  | D0491C |   4   |     1      |    1   |
|    3    | 2009 Ford Focus |  0,0  | V8S0CA |   4   |     1      |    1   |
```

The result displays all vehicles by the `owner` of `4`, registered and active both `1`, and the `modelName` displays the actual name from the `vehicle_database`.

The closest I have gotten is this query, however this displays duplicate results:

```
SELECT vehicle.id, vehicle.model, vehicle.state, vehicle.plates, db.year, db.brand, db.model
FROM `vehicles` vehicle, `vehicle_database` db
WHERE vehicle.owner = 4 AND vehicle.registered = 1 AND vehicle.active = 1;
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the condition to join both tables (by id)

```
SELECT vehicle.id, vehicle.model, vehicle.state, vehicle.plates, db.year, db.brand, db.model
FROM `vehicles` vehicle, `vehicle_database` db
WHERE vehicle.owner = 4 AND vehicle.registered = 1 AND vehicle.active = 1
AND vehicle.id=db.id;
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for, combining this with `CONCAT()` on the year, brand and model will give me the result I needed.